# How to print assert statement without the "&&"?

Tags: c, assert

I am printing my assert statement in the following manner:

```
assert((i==0) && "i is not zero");
Output: Assertion 'i==0 && i is not zero' failed.


What I want to be printed:
Output: 'i==0, i is not zero failed.
```

Comment: `assert(i==0 && i is not zero);` is a syntax error (unless you have some funky macros going on). What is your actual code?

Comment: That's not how `assert` works. Man page: "The `assert()` macro tests the given expression and if it is false, the calling process is terminated.  A diagnostic message is written to `stderr` and the `abort(3)` function is called, effectively terminating the program."

Comment: Using the standard `assert()` from `<assert.h>`, the output of a failed `assert()` is implementation defined.  To generate a specific output, OP will need to define own `assert()`.

Comment: Look at the design of `_Static_assert()` in C11.  It uses `_Static_assert(` _`constant-expression`_ `,` _`string-literal`_ `);` which is basically the format you're after.  That's quite different from the plain `assert` which is provided by the implementation.  You should not redesign plain `assert()` — it is reserved for the implementation; you should define your own alternative which does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write your own assert macro.  Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#undef myassert

#ifndef NDEBUG
#define myassert(test, why) ((test) ? (void) 0                      \
                             : (fprintf(stderr, "%s, %s failed.\n", \
                                        #test, why), abort()))
#else
#define myassert(test, why) ((void) 0)
#endif
```

and use it like this:

```
myassert(i == 0, "i is not zero");
```

Comment: Certainly `NDEBUG` should be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own assert macro, then. (Ninja'd by Ross Ridge.) My example, heavily modified per Jonathan Leffler's comments:

```
#undef my_assert
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define my_assert(expression, errormessage) ((void)0)
#else

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if __STDC_VERSION__-199901L >= 0
#define my_assert(expr, msg) \
    ((void)( (expr) ? 0 : do_assert(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, msg) ))

#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define my_assert(expr, msg) \
    ((void)( (expr) ? 0 : do_assert(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, msg) ))

#else
#define my_assert(expr, msg) \
    ((void)( (expr) ? 0 : do_assert(__FILE__, __LINE__, NULL, msg) ))
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_DO_ASSERT
#define HAVE_DO_ASSERT
static inline int do_assert(const char *const filename,
                            const unsigned long linenum,
                            const char *const funcname,
                            const char *const msg)
{
    if (funcname)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Line %lu, function %s(): %s\n", filename, linenum, funcname, msg);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Line %lu: %s\n", filename, linenum, msg);
    abort();
    return 0;
}
#endif

#endif
```

If you use

```
my_assert(i == 0, "nonzero i!");
```

in function `main()` in `example.c`, line 25, with `i` nonzero, you'll get

```
example.c: Line 25, function main(): nonzero i!
```

in standard error (plus something like `Aborted.`, depending on the operating system and C library).

Comment: Nit-picks: (1) You need to `#undef my_assert` since an assertion header can be included multiple times and the value of `NDEBUG` may change between the different places where it is included. (2) Because of multiple inclusion, you can't define a static function without protection: `#ifndef DO_ASSERT_DEFINED` / `#define DO_ASSERT_DEFINED` / …do_assert… / `#endif`.  (3) If you have no active assertions, you get a warning about an unused static function; you can avoid that with `static inline void do_assert(…) { … }`. (4) The C standard predefined identifier for the function name is `__func__`.

Comment: Note that the standard `assert` macro is a void expression, so it can be used on the LHS of a comma operator, for example.  Instead of the `do { … } while (0)` idiom, you'd need to use `((void)((expression == 0) ? do_assert(…) : 0))`, and then the inoperative macro needs to be `#define my_assert(expr, msg) ((void)0)`.  There are sound reasons for not wanting to allow `while (do_assert(s != 0, "s is a null pointer"), (c = *s++) != '\0')` as a loop condition, for example, but the standard permits `while (assert(s != 0), (c = *s++) != '\0')`.  (I didn't say it was a good example!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, those are valid points, so I had to edit my suggestion .. :D Since `expression` can have any scalar type, the idiom `((void)( (expression) ? 0 : do_assert(…) ))` seems more correct to me. I also fixed the `NDEBUG` case to reflect C99 (as you mentioned, to `((void)0)`).